# Setup OSx server + xcode bot, can't symbolicate crash logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm able to symbolicate for the builds I manually do in xcode, but not the ones that my bot is building every day. I'm wondering if it's because of where the files are being saved...
does anyone know where the xcode bots save the archives, has anyone had this issue?

I'm trying to open the crash logs in xcode, on the server that is doing the building.